# Can I do this with "yield" in Scala? (Nested for loops yielding a vector of combinations)

Tags: scala

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to any contemporary kind of coding. (BASIC an Pascal back in high school, a bit of Python a few years ago, and now I'm trying to teach myself Scala.)

This code is supposed to generate a randomized deck of cards with suits and values I customize in the first couple of lines. I have code that works, using mutable variables, but I always read it's better to try to avoid mutable variables, so I tried using "yield" instead. This was the result after I modified the code:

```
import util.Random.shuffle

val suits = Vector[String]("s", "m", "p")
val values = Vector[Int](1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9)

class Card(val suit:String, val value:Int) {}
class Deck() {
    var cardsInDeck:Vector[Card] = Vector()
}

def makeDeck(suits:Vector[String], values:Vector[Int]):Vector[Card] = {
    for (i <- suits) yield {
        for (j <- values) new Card(i, j) 
    }
}

val TheDeck = new Deck
TheDeck.cardsInDeck = util.Random.shuffle(makeDeck(suits, values))
for (i <- TheDeck.cardsInDeck) {
    println(s"${i.suit}${i.value}")
}
```

This gives me an error message, pointing at the arrow after 'i' and saying type mismatch.

Is there anything sort of like this that will work?

If not, do you think I should just stick with the original mutable variable version? (I'm assuming you can imagine how that basically went--start with a default-valued variable, and add to it one element at a time while iterating through the nested loops.)

Finally, I'm guessing Scala's already got some method or other built in that lets me do this for free. I think it's valuable to work out how to do it manually for general pedagogical purposes, but if there's a one-liner method out there I really should be using I'm interested in learning about it.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def makeDeck(suits: Vector[String], values: Vector[Int]): Vector[Card] = {
    for {
      i <- suits
      j <- values
    } yield new Card(i, j) 
}
```

You forgot the second yield in front of `new Card`. However, there is no need to nest the for loops, instead structure them like above.

You should consider making `cardsInDeck` into a `val` and a constructor parameter, so `Deck` can be immutable like `Card` is. It would also be convenient for `Deck` and `Card` to be case classes.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't quite figured out what the benefit is to case classes yet, but I'm still learning. As to whether the deck should be mutable or not, right now it seems like it has to be, since it will grow and shrink as the game proceeds. Does that not follow, though?

Comment: BTW it didn't even occur to me a second yield was needed there, but anyway I like your way better, easier to read etc.

Comment: Deck could be either mutable or immutable. If you make it immutable every operation that changes the deck will require that a new Deck object is created. Sometimes thats awkward for games and other simulations.